# What term do you use to find Japanese e-cards

Tags: translation

I can parse simple Japanese websites but can't find the term that I need to search for e-cards. e-card apparently has no translation so what would should I use to search for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try any one of these and it will work.

eカード、グリカ、グリーティングカード, etc.